# Installing Tensorflow Model Garden error " Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully." How to resolve this?

Tags: installation, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api, tensorflow-model-garden

I am trying to install the object detection module but i encountered an error which does not appear to the video im trying to follow.

I am on my environment (activated):

This are the commands i run in anaconda cmd.exe Prompt:

- git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
- cd models/research
- protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
- In git bash: cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
- back to anaconda cmd: python -m pip install .

In the last command this is what happen:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The first error before this is this:

```
Collecting pyyaml<5.4.0,>=5.1 (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1)
  Using cached PyYAML-5.3.1.tar.gz (269 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
```

The solutions that I tried are:

**1st solution:**

I tried upgrading the setuptools

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

in here after i run the python -m pip install . again it still have the same error "python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully."

**2nd solution**:

I tried to run this command

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

but still the same error "python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully."

**3rd solution**:

I tried to uninstall the Cython

```
pip uninstall Cython -y
```

and run the full commands again:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
cd models/research
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

#In git bash: 
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .

#back to anaconda cmd: 
python -m pip install .
```

Thus leading me to the error I have in the IMAGE.

I tried to install the aicore-content

```
pip install "ai-core-sdk[aicore-content]"
```

but in installing this I also get the same error in installing the object_detection module.

**Can anyone help me? I have been stack in here and can't continue on my project. Very much appreciated, Thank you!!**